# Setup Bitnami Nginx for subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, subdomain, bitnami

My domain is on AWS server with Bitnami Nginx installation. My goal is to create a subdomain for the test laravel application. Is this the correct bitnami.conf setting?

domain with certificates https://example.com
subdomain without certificates http://dev.example.com

`/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf:`

```
#Rewrite any http requests for (www)example.com to https version.
server {
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

#redirect block
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl_certificate "/etc/lego/certificates/example.com.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/lego/certificates/example.com.key";
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

#The example.com SSL website, main processing block
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate "/etc/lego/certificates/example.com.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/lego/certificates/example.com.key";
    server_name example.com;
    root /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/example.com/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/www.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.example.com
    root /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/dev.example.com/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/www.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. The new domain should work with the configuration you added, did you find any issue? The problem I see is that you removed the default "server" blocks from the file, did you remove them or did you skip the information?

Comment: @Jota Martos I haven't tried it yet, I'd rather ask. I'm using this code, but I just added a subdomain section for expert checking